# Generalized Cochran's Q Test

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, cochran-q

I have two groups of experimental data samples that are categorical, and my goal is similar to Pearson's chi-squared test (${ \chi ^{2}}$), to evaluate how likely it is that any observed difference between the sets arose by chance.

A sample from the first experiment is $D_1 = \{x_{1,1}: n_{1,1}, x_{1,2}: n_{1,2}, ... x_{1,t}: n_{1,t}\}$ and a sample from the second experiment is  $D_2 =\{x_{2,1}: n_{2,1}, x_{2,2}: n_{2,2}, ... x_{2,t}: n_{2,t}\}$. ( An example for data samples: $\{CAT: 10, DOG: 22, ... FROG: 44\}$)

Now, lets say I want to compare these data sets using $\chi^2$ test, but I want to stratify the data into different blocks (because observations are taken across time and I want to compare observations done at the same time directly to each other).

More concretely, let's say for each group, I add a block index: $D^b_i = \{x^b_{i,1}: n^b_{i,1}, x^b_{i,2}: n^b_{i,2}, ... x^b_{i,t}: n^b_{i,t}\}$  where $i \in {1, 2}$ and $b$ is the block number. If the data was dichotomous, i.e., $n_i^j$'s were only 0 or 1, I could use [Cochran's Q test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%27s_Q_test) to compare the two groups.

Is there such a test that generalizes Cochran's Q test to all categorical data and not just dichotomous data?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these are called Generalised (Cochran)-Mantel-Haenszel tests. One implementation (in R) [is documented here](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/stats/html/mantelhaen.test.html)

[This version](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/vcdExtra/html/CMHtest.html) allows for ordinal variables as well as nominal

These are both score tests for the interaction between your two variables of interest in a loglinear model with main effects for the block and the variables of interest.